# Composite battery adapter

Tags: canon, battery

Two of my cameras, a Canon A-1 and an original EOS Elan use batteries which are composites of multiple batteries. While this is no problem on the A-1, seeing as it uses very little power and the battery lasts about a decade, for the Elan, it is. The Elan has a built-in flash and uses a 2CR5 battery, a specially coupled grouping of two CR2 batteries. Is there any adapter to effectively combine two (less expensive) CR2 batteries into a single 2CR5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapters [do exist](http://www.ashburyintlgroup.com/BatteryAdapter2CR5.htm) to convert CR123 to 2CR5, but I haven't seen any actually for sale. It might not matter, though -- seems like you can get 2CR5 batteries for around $4 each, which is about the same as the price of a pair of CR2 or CR123 cells.